# Jmeter - Parameters missing

Tags: jmeter

We are using the jmeter recording template to see the api requests by our unsigned app.

When we use charles as the proxy, we are getting all the urls properly.

But when we use the jmeter recording template, we get 'MISSING PARAMETERS' for all GET requests. Essentially, jmeter does not get any parameters that are sent with the GET request.

POST requests work properly.

Any advice?

Comment: Parameters not showing even in the path?

Answer (score 0):

For convenience JMeter stores the request parameters under "Parameters" section of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

it's better to work with [attribute-value pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair) for [parameterization](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) or [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) purposes than having to edit the URL string which might be very long.

If you replay your recorded request(s) and look into `Request` tab of the  [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener you will see that the parameters are concatenated to protocol, domain, etc. in the URL:

[image]